# Synchronous POST with http-kit in clojure

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I am trying to do use the http-kit client library in clojure to do synchronous posts returning promises. Is there any way to limit the number of threads doing the actual post?

All the examples I could find of using the inbuilt thread pool use the lower level primitive function called `request` but they were all for http/get.

Thanks

Comment: I realised that I can use the [claypoole](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole) library to get want I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've seen http://http-kit.org/client.html#sync

My question is do you want to do a synchronous POST, or limit the number of threads? You can do a sync POST with 100 threads, it just so happens you're main thread will wait for the request to return.

Maybe more importantly, why do you want to limit the number of threads?

Also, see https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/master/src/org/httpkit/client.clj, specifically `request`. You can handle it a map of arguments, like 
`{:url "http://yoursite.com" :worker-pool my-thread-pool-executor}`

`my-thread-pool-executor` has to extend [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Specifically, you need to overload `submit` which is what the [RespListener](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/master/src/java/org/httpkit/client/RespListener.java) uses in http-kit. You could make `submit` synchronous with your own ExecutorService implementation so it runs on the same thread.